# How to setView in dialog on Android

Tags: android, dialog

I use below code to setView in dialog:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
TextView MyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_tv);
MyTextView.setText("test");
AlertDialog MyDialog;
AlertDialog.Builder MyBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
MyBuilder.setTitle("title");
MyBuilder.setView(layout);
MyDialog = MyBuilder.create();
MyDialog.show();
```

my_tv is a TextView in mylayout.xml.
But it occurs NullPointer error at line `MyTextView.setText("test");`.
How can I modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate the "MyTextView", you should instantiate by use follow code:

```
TextView MyTextView = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.my_tv);
```